# AWS Athena error: PatternSyntaxException Unclosed character class near index xxx

Tags: java, regex, amazon-web-services, hive

This query:

```
CREATE external table if NOT EXISTS s3_logs ( owner STRING, bucket STRING, time STRING, remote_ip STRING, requester STRING, request_id STRING, operation STRING, key STRING, request_uri STRING, http_status STRING, error_code STRING, bytes_sent INT, object_size INT, total_time INT, turn_around_time INT, referrer STRING, user_agent STRING, version_id STRING ) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
     "input.regex" = "([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) (\[[^\\]*\]) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) (-|[^ ]) (\".*?\") ([0-9]{3}) (-|[0-9]+) ([0-9]+) (-|[^ ]) ([0-9]+) (-|[^ ]) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) (-|[^ ])" ) 
LOCATION 's3://blah-logs'
```

when run yields this error:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
    java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: 
       Unclosed character class near index 156 
       ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([[^\]*]) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) (-|[^ ]) (".*?") ([0-9]{3}) (-|[0-9]+) ([0-9]+) (-|[^ ]) ([0-9]+) (-|[^ ]) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) (-|[^ ]) ^`
```

This same regex matches my input just fine on https://regex101.com and another java regex checker.

Comment: Use double backslashes to escape special chars, e.g. `\[[^\\]*\]` -> `\\[[^\\\\]*\\]`

Comment: I see you marked this as a duplicate but I don't see how anyone would find the other question using the error I received.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue using that hint? It is too common an issue, another answer "double the backslashes" won't be of any value on SO.

Comment: that hint did work, thanks